# How to use _lodash to retrieve value from Objects in Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, lodash

Here is my Array containing Objects, each Object has a ticker value:

```
[Object]
0: Object
    $$hashKey: "object:130"
    tags: Array[1]
    ticker: Object
        company: "Alcoa Inc."
        direction: "negative"
        percent: -3.89
        price: 14.59
        selected: true
        ticker: "AA"
```

There could be several objects, how would one use the `_lodash` library to pull out the `ticker.ticker` values out of each `Object`?

[image]

I've looked at their [each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) and [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) methods, but they are used on very basic arrays, with no documentation on how to target key value pairs inside.

`_.each([1, 2, 3], alert);`

`_.reduce(list, iteratee, [memo], [context])`

Ideally, what I'm trying to do is take that Array, and produce something like:

ticker1 = ticker1, & ticker2 = ticker2 or

`[ticker1, ticker2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use _.pluck: https://lodash.com/docs#pluck

```
console.log(_.pluck(_.pluck(list, 'ticker'), 'ticker'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kevinle/vj7e66zy/

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a property *path* to [pluck()](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck):

```
_.pluck(list, 'ticker.ticker');
```